# How to build dolphin on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, build, kde-plasma, kdelibs

I am not a Linux pro, but I have a task to modify KDE app "dolphin" for home using (modify address bar navigation mechanism). I think, that it would easy, but still have no understanding how to do this. Days of tries led me to the solution, that I should not build dolphin from dolphin repository (git://anongit.kde.org/dolphin), but from kde-baseapps repo:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core  build-essential libkactivities-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep dolphin
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kde-baseapps && cd kde-baseapps && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix` ..
make -j3
cd dolphin/src/
./dolphin4
```

Next I think, that I can find source code in "kde-baseapps" folder, but it references to "/usr/include" *.h-files, that references to corresponding *.cpp-files in "kdelibs" package.
That's right, that I should download "kdelibs" sources, modify them and build? That is right way to resolve task or exists a better way to do this?

Comment: sudo apt-get install qtwebengine5-dev libdebconf-kde-dev kded5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, exists a better solution. kdelibs compilation isn't necessary, it is possible to modify only dolphin source code by this bash commands (from ~ dir):

```
mkdir src
cd src
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep kde-baseapps
apt-get source kde-baseapps
cd kde-baseapps-4.13.3/dolphin/src/
patch < ~/your.patch
cd ../..
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```